# How to boot from APSF volume?

Tags: mojave, partition, startup, dual-boot, disk-volume

I am trying to run 2 identical MacOS on my MacBook pro.

I am following the following instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891

So far, I have added an APFS Volume, with flexible size, installed Mojave on it (following the installer wizard) and I can see it in disk utility:

[image]

However, when I try to change the boot settig in startup disk, I can't find it:

[image]

Why can't I see the new volume? Ideally I would like to be prompted on which volume I would like to boot from when I turn on the macbook.

Additional Information:
[image]

Comment: Does it show up when you boot while holding down the Option key? That is the standard way of selecting a boot volume on boot.

Comment: It doesn't show up there either.

Comment: It will help if you provide additional information. Can you post your results from typing “diskutil list” inside the terminal app located in your utilities folder?

Comment: Sure, added it to my question. Volume 2 is the new volume.

Comment: Just tried removing the volume and making a partition instead, but its the same.

Comment: OK I got it working using a conventional partition.

Comment: It looks like it did not correctly install. Disk1s4 and Disk1s5 don’t contain the ~12GB a fresh install takes up.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Upon checking it again with my current partition it has 12G.